# difference between feed_dict and list in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to know the difference between `feed_dict` and just `list`. I though Y is `y_data`.

Below is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x_data = [[1., 2.], [2., 3.], [3., 1.], [4., 3.], [5., 3.], [6., 2.]]
y_data = [[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1]]
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
W = tf.Variable([[1.], [1.]])
b = tf.Variable([1.])
c = 1-Y
d = 1-y_data
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())    
    print(sess.run(c, feed_dict={Y: y_data}))
    print(sess.run(d))
```

I got an error like below:

```
d = 1-y_data  
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: Well you do `1` which is an `int` `-` the `list` `y-data`. I don't know what you are trying to achieve... if you want the entire list - 1. You can so something like `d = [ y-1 for y in y_data]`

Comment: Broadcasting operations like subtracting every element from 1 aren't defined for Python's `list` type, though they are for `np.array` and related types.

Comment: How does this relate to feed_dict? The error occurs before you ever get there.

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with tensorflow. You have a bunch of tensorflow code but non of this is related to your error. If you remove all unrelated things you will get just a plain python:

```
y_data = [[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1]]
d = 1-y_data
```

which clearly will not work because 1 is an int, y_data is a list.

Comment: thank you for you comment. But, What I want to know exactly is why 1-Y is possible. I thought Y is also a kind of a list.

Comment: @ChoiWoo-seong 1 - y is possible because Y is a placeholder. So [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting#what_is_broadcasting) is used

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing completely different objects in this post.

This makes your question a bit irrelevant.

One should understand that every computation with Tensorflow must occur in the graph that you create through tf.placeholder, tf.Variable or other functions that bind these through so called 'graph ops'.

In this context, `Y, W` and `b` are variables (or placeholders which will act like variables after you feed them when 'executing`through`sess.run`).

Furthermore, `1-Y` is only defining a `graph op`. To demonstrate this, I modified your code by addind `print Y` and `print c` right after their declarations.

The result is

```
Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("sub:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
```

As you can see, `Y` is a placeholder, but `c` is a subtraction op.

So it is normal that it works. If you ask about the technicality that makes it possible, I am not 100% sure but probably they make something like operator overloading to make it seamless.

To see that it is in fact the same, you could also this:

c2 = tf.subtract(1.0, Y)

See [tf.subtract](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/subtract) and [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for further information.